# How to replicate Androids stock camera orientation change

Tags: java, c#, android, camera, surface

I have an Samsung Edge, API 24, Android 7.0 and a Samsung Tablet, API 24, Android 7.0.

Skip this blockquote part if you don't want to know about the backstory:

> I want to recreate the stock camera and implement it into my app. I'm
>   actually very close to having it finished (using Xamarin.Android +
>   C#), using the [Xamarin Version of the Google Camera Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Camera2VideoSample/Camera2VideoSample).
>
> However there are orientation problems left... 180° rotations
>   (landscape -> reverse landspace or vice versa) don't trigger the
>   "SurfaceChanged" event, which is used to set the matrix of the surface
>   to make it display correctly.
>
> I've seen different approaches, one seems stable: Fix the orientation
>   to landscape and handle orientations myself.

Looking at the stock camera of my two devices, I see that the camera preview never moves a bit, only the button rotate + the activity (status bar moves to top on orientation change)
How is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

An abstract idea, or code snippets in Java or C# would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the activity orientation on start (for example, inside `onResume` method):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

Specify in `AndroidManifest.xml` that you want the activity to listen to orientation changes:

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    ...
```

Then process the orientation changes inside activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // rotate buttons using newConfig.orientation value
}
```

Comment: But this makes me have my status bar always at the same edge of my device. This is not what I was asking about.

Comment: That's interesting, status bar is not moving in standard camera app on my devices with Android 7.0 and 8.1

Comment: I just tested it on a 6.0 Tablet, and it has the same behaviour i described.

Comment: Are both tablets from Samsung? They can use some internal, undocumented API like `pushStatusBarToThatSideOfScreen` :)

Comment: Yes :D 3 samsung devices that I have tested so far. Interesting... on a Huawei (Android 7.0), the status bar sticks to the top respective to portrait, never changing on orientation changes... I guess the best way is really to fix the orientation and handle the rest on my own (the way you explained it). This makes me sad tbh

Comment: Please accept the sad answer then :) status bar sticks for me on LG(Nexus) and Xiaomi devices as well